# Microsoft Active Directory Administrator privileges

Tags: active-directory

We have a problem:

*all our developers have full admin rights on their computers.*

I set up a group called "Local administrators" through a GPO policy, which includes all domain users (developers), giving them admin privileges on their workstations. Members can make changes to other  user profiles if they connect via RDP.

For example, if I RDP into George's computer with my domain user, I can delete all his files in C:\Users\George.

I'm concerned about this security risk and want to find a solution.

Comment: the question is furthermore, why do they need it?

Comment: A solution to terrible design? Restore or setup the current environment in test, remove Administrator permissions, and have them validate their apps.

Comment: To make their life easier. They always use administrator privileges for testing, modifying files, etc. So they need the admin privileges. Also, I do not want to disturb me every time they install a new package for their visual studio, start the cmd as admin, change permission of files, etc. @Greg Askew your comment is not a solution because I need to validate more than 50 apps.

Comment: What if I am out of the office for 1-2 weeks? I will write them from the beach "Wait I will connect to ur computer to install the software/plugin/uninstall" Also with the LAPS I need to connect to VPN, open the AD, and give them the password, which is not working for me. I do not want to act as a barrier for their job. I want them to write code and to not complain. But also I want to restrict some things!

Comment: As it stands, your question needs more focus. It sounds like you accidentally made all domain users administrators by adding them to the local Administrators group of every computer? But it's not clear what exactly happened. It is also not clear, why you do not undo the change? It's easier to help you if you state the exact problem you have, what you have tried to solve it and where the challenges were. Then a solution can be suggested. Keep in mind that Serverfault or StackExchange is a Q&A style board where discussions are difficult to be had and also not intended.

Comment: That is not a good excuse for neglecting to provide your users with a local account that they can use to perform activities that require elevated privileges.

Comment: Check out Microsoft LAPS. Have a single administrator account per computer with a rotating password. Users can request the current password for their own computer when they need it. They should NOT do regular work with an administrative account.

Answer (score 3):

If your developers really need local administrator rights, you should at least make each developer only administrator of his/her own computer.

Having all users being administrators on all machines is a terrible design and just asking for troubles.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you suggest to me how to make each user administrator to their computer with GPO? I do not want to go all around the computers and stop their work for 10-15 minutes.

Comment: You can't do it with GPO, unless you create a specific GPO per computer and apply it to the specific computer. The only way using GPO I see is to create a script (PowerShell) that you deploy to all computers. The script would have to do the heavy lifting, tho.

Comment: Yep, I was thinking like you Daniel,  first thought to create a separate group for each user and then apply it to the computer, but like you think the script would be a better choice!

Comment: Thanks for the opinions. I will just make each user of the computer Administrator without a group. I think that this will be the best solution that fits the company's need

Comment: You can absolutely do this with a single GPO -- but you will need a group per machine.  Create a group per machine COMPUTERNAME_admin (or whatever), add the appropriate users in, then in the GPP Item, configure it to add %COMPUTERNAME%_admin group to the local administrators group.  The environment variable will expand and select the correct group from AD.

Comment: Yeah, what Massimo and Daniel said. If you have machine names that give some hint as to who the admin user should be, that would help... but you probably don't want to rename all your computers if not.